# pass a parameter to collection_select's text_method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

I have the following:

```
<%= collection_select 'product', 'id', @products, 'id', :description %>
```

- a list of products matched by the preceding keyword search.

And I'd like to use more specific description, which is built by model's method `specific_description(keyword)`. Though model doesn't have access to the keyword (params[:q]). 
What can be used to pass a parameter to the text_method (description in my case) when using collection_select?

Answer (score 1):

Add `attr_accessor :keyword` to the `Product` model and use it inside `specific_description`:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :keyword

  def specific_description
    # use @keyword here
  end
end
```

In controller:

```
@products.each { |product| product.keyword = params[:q] }
```

Now you can call `collection_select` without passing parameter to `specific_description`:

```
<%= collection_select 'product', 'id', @products, 'id', :specific_description %>
```